# Add dynamic dotnet webcontrol into attribute value of static html

Tags: .net

Easy one to explain. Is there any way I can do this:

```
<div id="header" style='<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litBackgroundImage"></asp:Literal>' >
```

It looks valid, but Visual Studio will not recognise litBackgroundImage as a valid control in the code-behind. Setting the div as runat="server" won't work either because the style property is read-only.

Any suggestions gratefully received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `runat="server"` to your div and then you can access it from server-side, so you can set the `style` attribute dynamically.

Comment: You can't set style dynamically, as I said above - it's read only.

Comment: @Matt, I think that BlueCode was talking about using the Attributes property instead of the Style property.

Answer (score 1):

This ***might*** work:

```
HtmlControl headerDiv = (HtmlControl)this.FindControl("header");
headerDiv.Attributes.Add("class", **NAMEOFCSSCLASSTOUSE**);
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work. You will have to make sure that your style is a css class in a css file.

**EDIT**

After testing the above won't work, but the following worked fine for me:

```
<div id="header3" runat="server">This is header3 ...</div>
```

and in the code-behind:

```
header3.Attributes("style") = "height: 100px; background-color: red;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you nesting your Literal inside a `<form>` tag? It's an obvious answer but one worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">...</div>
```

and

```
div1.Style["width"] = "100px";
div1.Style["color"] = "#FF0000";
```